# How to route traffic through a VM's host when under host-only

Tags: windows, networking, routes, virtualbox

I'm using virtualbox (under windows) with host-only and I'm trying to make the host (that's running windows) forward the packets that are arriving from the virtual machine's interface to the interface that has an internet connection so the virtual machine can also have internet access.
In Ubuntu I did this simply like this:

> iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE

How could I do this under windows?

Comment: Why use host-only when it sounds like you really want to use a NAT or bridged virtual adapter?

Comment: I have to use Host-Only because I want to intercept any packages sent/received by the virtual machine.